# Open CV Text Detection

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

I want to detect each word without running any kind of **OCR technology**. My Idea is to create rectangle around each word in this picture. To achieve this I have made a python script which I have attached below, which does not match my expectation. Basically I want to:

1. draw rectangle around each word.(I don't care actually if it is a word or not) Depending upon black color specially I want to draw rectangles,Like if black colors have been occurred very closely then I can assume that it is a word. Like This: [image: this]

My Python script:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


image = cv2.imread('Capture.JPG')
original = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0,0, 0], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([200,200, 200], dtype="uint8")
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

area = 0
for c in cnts:
    area += cv2.contourArea(c)
    cv2.drawContours(original,[c], 0, (0,0,0), 1)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    color = list(np.random.random(size=3) * 256)
    cv2.rectangle(original, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 1)

    print(c)
print(area)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.waitKey()
```